# MongoDB copying key and value from one key and value to another

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to copy key and value to field of each document.

Document example "db.ruj_users.find()":

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("52fd5f7ae1ab21223018121d"),    
    "email_notification" : "on",
    "email_notification_interval" : "immediately",    
    "news_notification" : "on",
    "notifs" : [ 
        {}
    ],

}
```

Code that I have tried:

```
db.ruj_users.find().snapshot().forEach(function(elemt) {
    elemt.notifs.emailNotif = elemt.email_notification;
    elemt.notifs.emailNotifIntrval = elemt.email_notification_interval;    
    elemt.notifs.newsNotif = elemt.news_notification;


db.ruj_users.notifs.update(
{$set:[
    elemt
    ]     
})
```

error received: uncaught exception: assert failed : need an object

Basically, I want to organize my documents so I want to copy "email_notifcations, email_notifications_interval, and news_notification" into "notifs" then delete the old entries.

Comment: could you specify what is the problem in details ?

Comment: I updated the question has it didn't display fully.

Comment: Your update syntax is missing a condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query set `notifs` field and delete all another (`"email_notifcations"`, `"email_notifications_interval"` and `"news_notification"`), because of used `update` command without `$set` operator.

```
db.ruj_users.find().forEach(function (elem) {
    var obj = {
        emailNotif: elem.email_notification,
        emailNotifIntrval: elem.email_notification_interval,    
        newsNotif: elem.news_notification,
    };
    db.ruj_users.update({_id: elem._id}, { notifs: obj });
})
```

Be sure that your documents haven't any another fields (except `_id`), because this fields will be removed too. In this case you should rewrite query with `$set` operator.